# Accessing command line (cmd) from RStudio with system() command

Tags: r, machine-learning

I want to use the `system()` command to access the command line (`cmd`) from `RStudio`. But when I place my command in an R script, an error is displayed and indicates that R does not accept the syntax. The command is:

```
system("C:\Program Files\ANSYS Inc\v150\ANSYS\bin\winx64\ansys150.exe" -p ane3fl -dir "C:\Users\hamdani\Documents" -j "hamid" -s read -l en-us -b -i "C:\Users\hamdani\Documents\Plane Stress Bracket.txt" -o "C:\Users\hamdani\Documents\fichier.out")
```

The error is:

```
Error: '\P' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting "'"C:\P"
```

When I place the command directly in the System Command, it works very well:

```
"C:\Users\hamdani\Documents" -j "hamid" -s read -l en-us -b -i "C:\Users\hamdani\Documents\Plane Stress Bracket.txt" -o "C:\Users\hamdani\Documents\fichier.out"
```

Comment: Questions only about R code are off topic here. This might be OK on [SO], if you wait, we can try to migrate it there.

Comment: Please read `help(system)` more carefully. The _entire command has to be one string_ and you can escape arguments there by protecting arguments.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the way that you must enter strings for R.  Your command includes the path to the executable and files, so part of the command is:

```
system("C:\Program Files\ANSYS Inc\v150\ANSYS\bin\winx64\ansys150.exe" ...
```

But R uses backslash `\` to signal an escape sequence, specialized use of characters such as `\n` to represent a newline character. Since `\` signals an escape sequence is about to start, if you want a backslash character, you must escape the escape, i.e. the way to get a single backslash character in your string is to type `\\`. You command includes many backslashes.  You need to double all of them to get by this type of error.